# Getting libc.so file not found error in python

Tags: python, libc

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 391, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 385, in main
    find_rop_gadgets('libc.so')
  File "test.py", line 78, in find_rop_gadgets
    e = elf.ELF(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pwnlib/elf/__init__.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.file = open(path,'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libc.so'
```

I am new to python,So Please if anyone could help me out here.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not the proper page where to ask such questions. I've flagged the question so a moderator can migrate it.

Comment: you probably need the full path to libc.so.

Comment: You've only shown an exception, you need to also show the code if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu 14.04. You should try the command below:

```
sudo ln -s `locate libc.so.6` /lib/libc.so
```

Or:

```
sudo ln -s `locate libc.so.6` /lib/libc.so.6
```